# Accessing one row at a time in an array

Tags: python, list

Say I have a matrix of strings

```
array = [['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'],
         ['I', 'am', 'doing', 'okay'],
         ['Okay', 'did','you', 'do', 'your', 'hw','?']]
```

And I want to search every other line for key words since there suppose to be two people in a conversation.

For example this, matrix has 3 rows and every odd line corresponds to person A and every even line corresponds to person B.

However, I just care about what person A writes, since I'm only searching for words person A said.

Comment: do you mean "how to iterate over the words in every even/odd row"?

Comment: With your example `array` (which is really a list of lists), what output do you want? Do you have some example keywords you would want to search for and what you would expect in response?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example. Your question doesn't make it clear what you want to do with matching lines, but the idea is that you skip every other line with a slice `[::2]`. This does create a copy of your list, so working with indices directly like `xrange(0, len(array), 2)` may be more efficient (use `range()` in Python3).

```
keywords = ['did', 'you']

array = [['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'],
         ['I', 'am', 'doing', 'okay'],
         ['Okay', 'did','you', 'do', 'your', 'hw','?']]

print [line for line in array[::2] if any(key in line for key in keywords)]
```

Comment: OP doesn't give his requested output, but I would wager it looks more like `itertools.chain.from_iterable([[word for word in line if word in keywords] for line in array[::2]])`

Comment: That's fair. I'll ask him to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue to clear up is terminology. Technically, what you have is *not* an array or a matrix. You have a list of lists.

To iterate over every other line, you can use list indexing. For a list `A`, this takes the format `A[start:stop:step]`, where *start*, *stop* and *step* are integers (positive or negative) and *stop* is not included in the range. If you omit an integer, it is assumed to be `0` for *start*, `None` for *end*, `0` for *step*.

Therefore, to iterate over the first person's words, you can use:

```
for words_a in array[::2]:
    # do something
```

Or, for the second person's words, use `array[1::2]`.

Note the above method involves building new lists. A more memory-efficient method is to use an iterator, such as `itertools.slice`:

```
from itertools import islice

for words_a in islice(array, 0, None, 2):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind eschewing the often-idiomatic list comprehension, you could use a simple `for` loop with a manual `next` call afterwards. This has the advantage of having a smaller memory footprint, but is obviously more verbose.

```
acc = []

arrayiter = iter(array)

for line in arrayiter:
    acc.extend([word for word in line if word in keywords])
    next(arrayiter, None)  # skips the next line
```

Comment: You could have the best of both worlds with the `xrange()` generator. `[array[i] for i in xrange(0, len(array), 2) if any(key in array[i] for key in keywords)]`. Overly complicated comprehensions can ofuscate meaning, but I think this usage is probably fine.

Comment: @HansMusgrave xrange belongs to python2, please do not recommend python2

Comment: @coldspeed I was wrong a couple days ago in not checking that OP had a python3.x tag, but Python2 is still the default in many major operating systems, and all recent credible studies indicate that there are more current developers in Python2 than Python3. If OP happens to have Python2, `range()` will have undesirable performance characteristics. What is the primary argument for recommending Python3 when OP didn't ask for it and more likely than not doesn't use it?

Comment: @HansMusgrave The primary argument is that [python2 is being deprecated](https://pythonclock.org/).

Comment: @coldspeed Deprecated or not, isn't it still worth properly answering the most likely interpretation of OP's question?

Comment: @HansMusgrave Unless otherwise stated or implied by code, _all questions are assumed to contain code written in python3_. This is an implicit agreement among the regulars here and it isn't really up for debate. If you feel up for a discussion, come on down to the python chatroom and try arguing your case. Good luck though. Python2 is on its way out.

Comment: @coldspeed That was all I was curious about. You've been around longer than I had, and I was wondering if there were any hard and fast reasons. Is that mentioned in any documentation/guidelines anywhere? If not, is it reasonable to add it? I think the Python2/3 debate was the core of our misunderstanding last time too.

Comment: @HansMusgrave no, but it is generally implied :) Because these questions will stick around, and as they get older, and as python2's popularity continues to decrease, the answers need to stay current (aka python3) else they will become useless.

Comment: @coldspeed That's fair. Thank you for your help :)